# MVC jquery autocomplete, how do I pick up the selected Id?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my view I have;

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddExistingSite", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "siteRows" }))
            {

                <input type="text" name="q" style="width: 800px" 
                       data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("SiteSearch", "DataService", new { contractId = @Model.Contract.ContractId })" />
                <input type="submit" value="Add site to contract" />
            }
```

In my controller I have

```
public ActionResult SiteSearch(string term, int contractId)
    {
        using (var db = new SherryGreenGroupEntities())
        {
            var sites = db.Sites
                .Include("SiteContracts")
                .Where(x => x.SiteContracts.All(y => y.ContractId != contractId || y.EndDate.HasValue)  &&
                    x.Address.Contains(term))
                .Take(10)
                .Select(x => new { id = x.SiteId, label = x.Address }).ToList();
            return this.Json(sites, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

I have set up jquery;

```
$(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete") });
});
```

Now autocomplete is working, but what I want to know is what do I do to pick up the selected item's Id so I can post it to the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you only have a single text field inside your form that will hold the selected value. If you need the corresponding id you could add a hidden field that will be used to store this information:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddExistingSite", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "siteRows" }))
{
    <input type="text" name="q" style="width: 800px" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("SiteSearch", "DataService", new { contractId = @Model.Contract.ContractId })" />
    <input type="hidden" name="itemId" class="itemId" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add site to contract" />
}
```

and then subscribe to the [`select`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) event of the autocomplete and update it with the corresponding value:

```
$(':input[data-autocomplete]').each(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: $(this).attr('data-autocomplete'),
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).closest('form').find('.itemId').val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Now inside the target controller action it's trivial to get both the label and the id:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddExistingSite(string q, string itemId)
{
    ...
}
```

Obviously all this is just a raw example. In a real application you should not be hardcoding input fields in your views but you should be using HTML helpers to generate them and you should obviously be using view models.